# HTML Using [Tab] to execute default functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem, trying to use `[TAB]` to call methods. I've used `tabby.js` so, I can use `[TAB]` in the `textarea` but now I wanted `[TAB]` to be used as help.

For example : When I write a name before, I want to be able to recall all the name I've tippen juste by typing `[TAB]`. I wanted to create a method with `javascript` or `PHP` but I really have no idea how I shold do.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You can't use PHP to control what keys do when the user is in the browser. And you shouldn't change the default behaviour for keys like `tab` because users naturally expect the default behaviour - if you change `tab` to recall a list of names, then how does the user tab out of the field?

Comment: Year, I understand. Thank you. So I've already provided a message to inform the user. So using PHP isn't possible. Okay. Is it possible with javascript ?